# Producing gold nano flakes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nanotechnology

In terms of producing gold nano flakes, Guo et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.colsurfa.2005.11.075.)] added aniline to the solution of chloroauric acid in ethylene glycol at 95 °C. However, I couldn't figure out the step by step chemical reaction in it. Can anyone please explain me the reaction procedure or guide me to the relevant source?

#### References

1. Guo, Z.; Zhang, Y.; DuanMu, Y.; Xu, L.; Xie, S.; Gu, N. Facile Synthesis of Micrometer-Sized Gold Nanoplates through an Aniline-Assisted Route in Ethylene Glycol Solution. *Colloids and Surfaces A: Physicochemical and Engineering Aspects* **2006**, 278 (1), 33–38. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.colsurfa.2005.11.075.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that ethylene glycol in this reaction is used as a [solvent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diethylene_glycol) and [Aniline](http://www.scientific.net/SSP.121-123.251) is used as a reducing agent. Ethylene glycol solution heated with chloroauric acid produces $Au^{3+}$ ions (first 20 min) which is then reduced to $Au^{0}$  (3hr reaction) in the presence of aniline. Because there is no stirring during those 3 hrs (so less agitation of the reaction mixture)there is less formation of gold nanoparticle and more gold nano flakes are formed.

May be this [paper will](http://iopscience.iop.org/0957-4484/23/1/015602/article) help you, it has a similar mechanism

[image: enter image description]